# How to remove the last SVG button from the site? The SVG button are only supposed to go in between each word

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[How the button look on the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xYj1.png)

```
<div className="teams-row">
                {
                    specialTeams.map(
                        (specialTeam) => <span key={specialTeam._id}>{specialTeam.name}
                            <svg className="dot-svg" width="6" height="6" viewBox="0 0 6 6" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <ellipse cx="2.94396" cy="3" rx="2.94396" ry="3" fill="#3B5889" />
                            </svg>
                        </span>

                    )
                }
            </div>
```

Hello everyone! Im trying to get the last SVG button removed after the "engine operator." I posted a small snippet of code above with the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try conditionally rendering the SVG only if it isn't the last element. Something like this:

```
<div className="teams-row">
    {specialTeams.map((specialTeam, index) => <span key={specialTeam._id}> 
        {specialTeam.name}
        {(index != specialTeams.length - 1) &&  <svg className="dot-svg" width="6" height="6" viewBox="0 0 6 6" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <ellipse cx="2.94396" cy="3" rx="2.94396" ry="3" fill="#3B5889" />
        </svg>}
     </span>
    )}
</div>
```